# ASP.NET Reporting alternatives for shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, report

I am using a ASP.NET with c# website and MSSQL Server 2005 DB.

Will be hosting on a **shared hosting provider**..**so i cannot install any runtimes/other software or services.** i dont have MSRS (Microsot reporting services) or others as well.

I need to find some **good reporting alternatives besides** Crystal Reports and other heavily paid services.

I need to be able to generate reports with grouping , query based, cumulative, formula based, sub reports within one report, simple graphs and charts, etc

**Please help me with this issue.**

(i tried LogiReports from http://www.freereporting.com/product/index.html)
but it is difficult to use.

Thanks and Regards

prad

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Telerik Reports](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx)?  It does not need any special software installed on your deployment servers.  The reports that you create are in a dll that deploy along with your application.  It is not free, but it is still very nice.